# R shiny :: How to change the value of reactiveTimer during process

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make a code for read csv file repeatedly by interval time.

( just example)
The csv file is stored data by every 1sec
If the value in csv file is under the threshhold  , I want to change the interval time for reading csv file.

```
if(data$quality[nrow(data)]<6){
              mytime$timer=reactiveTimer(0.5*60*1000)
              return(mytime$timer)
}
```

But it does not work well.
Does anyone have an idea to change value of `reactiveTimer`?

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)



function(input, output, session) {
  

  mytime<-reactiveValues(inc=0, timer=reactiveTimer(20000), started=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$ab1, {
    mytime$started<-TRUE
    mytime$timer <- reactiveTimer(as.numeric(input$interval)*60*1000)
  })
  observeEvent(input$ab2, {mytime$started<-FALSE})
  observeEvent(input$ab3, {
    mytime$started<-FALSE
    mytime$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
  })


  
  observe({
    if (input$ab1==0){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      
      mytime$timer()
      
      
      if(isolate(mytime$started)){
        mytime$inc<-isolate(mytime$inc)+1
        
       
            
            #Read file/////////////////
        
            data<- read_delim("wine_quality_Red.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
    
            
            output$table=DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(data))
            
            
            
            if(data$quality[nrow(data)]<6){
              mytime$timer=reactiveTimer(0.5*60*1000)
              return(mytime$timer)
              
            }else{
              
              output$Plot1=renderPlot({
                plot(data$`fixed acidity`,data$density)
              })
              
            }
            
      }
    }
        
  })
  
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("TEST"), 
  
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     
      
      #Interval for reloading file
      textInput("interval", "Input interval time for reloading [min]:", value = "5"),
      
      
      #Operation button
      tags$hr(),
      strong("Operation:"),
      textOutput("mytext"),
      br(),
      br(),
      actionButton("ab1","START",class = "btn-warning"),
      br(),
      br(),
      actionButton("ab2","PAUSE",class = "btn-warning"),
      br(),
      br(),
      actionButton("ab3","STOP",class = "btn-warning")
      
      
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Plot" , plotOutput("Plot1")),
                  tabPanel("Table", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                  )
    )
  )
    
)
```

[example datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7US2T.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide an example data file `wine_quality_Red.csv`. 2 questions: 1. is `data$quality` a column? If yes, then using `if(data$quality<6)` is not really save, because only the first row is evaluated. 2. do you only want to show the plot if data$quality is >6?

Comment: @starja Thank you for your comment. You can see the data file from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/ 

Also, I have a mistake,
`if(data$quality<6)` is wrong. >>> `if(data$quality[nrow(data)] <6) ` is correct.

I correct my question.